# Поиск элемента с двумя и более цифрами

Tags: mysql

В базе есть поле, в котором хранятся номера заказов в форматах:
Z1,B4,G10

```
SELECT `number` FROM `orders` WHERE `number` RLIKE '^Z.*' order by `number` desc limit 1
```

Вот такой запрос ищет последний заказ по букве, но почему-то если номера заказа с 2 цифрами, то он не видит его и выдает Z9 (хотя в базе есть Z15). В чем причина?

Comment: В том, что сортировка ведется по строкам. Строка `Z15` всегда будет больше строки `Z9`, потому что она длиннее.

Comment: Делайте номера с фиксированным количеством разрядов, например, z09, z10, ... z15, тогда и сортировка будет работать.

Comment: Если в номере всегда в начале только одна буква, а потом цифра, то можно разделить их в запросе на составляющие и делать сортировку сначала по буквам, а затем по цифрам.

Comment: Как вариант (скорее, временный) можно использовать следующее: `ORDER BY LENGTH(\`number\`) DESC, \`number\` DESC` - тогда "длинные" числа будут первыми